# Мне нужно что бы воспроизводились не только mp3 ссылки в QMediaPlayer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, streaming, qmediaplayer

у меня есть код

```
def radio_create(self, url):
    name = QMediaPlayer(self)
    name.setMedia(QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(url)))
    return name
```

но он воспроизводит только mp3 файлы мне же нужно что бы он мог воспроизводить любую мухыку или хотя бы .aac

Если подробнее, то я делаю приложение с потоковым радио и мне бы хотелось что бы в прямом эфире могли воспроизводиться не только mp3 ссылки

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/57675/which-file-formats-or-codecs-does-qmediaplayer-support/3

Comment: @Alexander Chernin
мне кажется кодеки не помогут для потокового радио которое идет в реальном времени

Comment: Зачем же они нужны тогда ? http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_32873_0.html

Comment: значит мне нужно просто установить набор кодеков? или как, я просто новичок а с этим вообще не разбирался